# Android 5.0+ AudioManager setMode not working

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

i am working on AudioManager which is a Android SystemService. 
with Android System 5.0+ , i encounter a problem which AudioManager the setMode method is not working .

i through a test , 
Android M, Lollipop.. 5.0+ version ,  AudioManager setMode is not working .
example :

```
public void initAudioImageIcon(boolean initLoad) {
    boolean isAudioHeaderMode = IMSharedPreferences.getBooleanExtra(this, IMSPConstant.SP_NAME_MESSAGE,
            IMSPConstant.SP_KEY_AUDIO_HEADER_MODE);


    if (isAudioHeaderMode) {
        mAudioHanderMode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL) , but android system 5.0+ no any change, getMode() == AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
        setAudioMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        if (!initLoad) {
            showAudioModePrompt(this.getText(R.string.im_audio_in_call), 1000);
        }
    } else {
        mAudioHanderMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setAudioMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        if (!initLoad) {
            showAudioModePrompt(this.getText(R.string.im_audio_in_speeker), 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

but Android 3.0+,4.0+ is ok ,only 5.0+ .
so ,i don`t know where happen mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With audio mode set to :

```
setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

while my audio stream is set to STREAM_MUSIC I can easily route audio to earpiece. I have tested it myself in AOSP Lollipop code.

Here in the question you have never mentioned about your stream type. Do set your stream to STREAM_MUSIC or STREAM_VOICE_CALL and the code should work for you too.

Comment: i follow your suggestion , 
My stream type is :
`//audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
`

My tested earpiece code is :
`setAudioMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
`

and speaker code is :
`setAudioMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
 audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`
. The code can not work in earpiece , with your suggestion have any diff? 
i try `STREAM_MUSIC` and `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` stream type that tested my Lollipop and M  ,it can`t work.

Comment: getStreamMaxVolume is not the way to set the stream. Pls set stream in the audio source you are trying to play. Read Android documentation and do try. This code is working 100% in lollipop.

Comment: very sorry , i made a big mistake what do getStreamMaxVolume as setStreamType . thanks.

Comment: @Saurav can we set stream type for webview?

Comment: Since this is audiomanager api if you have audiomanager instance u can call it from anywhere .

Answer (score 1):

In android Lollipop `setAudioMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)` is restricted. It can be used only by system application with `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission. However you can use `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` and `MODE_NORMAL` in normal applications.

Comment: Thanks , so it is . but `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` and `MODE_NORMAL` is speaker voice . if i wanna use the handset Mode that is method which  place my app in `/system/app` folder that enhance app level ?   There are other methods ?

Comment: I did not understand your query well but I m guessing you are trying to play audio in earpiece. For that you can set mode as MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION and set speaker to false. Please up-vote my answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry, i try it. `audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            setAudioMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);`   but it always to play audio in speaker .     i want to what play audio in earpiece.   My Android device is Android M.

Comment: i try  `setMode( AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION )`, but `getMode() ` is 0  (AudioManager. MODE_NORMAL).  i`m guessing the reason that is audio always in speaker.  because the mode is 0.  no change!

Comment: Please can you post code of your initialization of audio source? Like AudioTrack or Soundpool ?? In that initialization you have to set the stream.  For SoundPool : SoundPool(int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality)  And for Audio track the code would look like : AudioTrack(int streamType, int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat, int bufferSizeInBytes, int mode, int sessionId)