# Xamarin Android AudioManager modes not being set

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-audiomanager

I am attempting to change Mode and RingerMode to Normal and Vibrate, respectively, once a video call is finished. Here is my code:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);

am.Mode = Mode.Normal;
am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Vibrate;

Console.WriteLine("AudioSettings Set To: {0}, {1}", am.Mode, am.RingerMode);
```

However, the modes are not being set. There is no exception or error as to why this is not working. I can't find any resources online that point to the issue I am having. Here is what the above Console.WriteLine statement prints out:

```
AudioSettings Set To: InCommunication, Silent
```

Why could this be happening? Because this is not working, when the app is closed, it maintains the Mode of **InCommunication** for the device, which is not ideal at all.

**Update:** This was resolved. Please see my answer below.

Comment: What API-level are you testing on?

Comment: @SushiHangover I have tested this on 22, 23, and 24

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871328/android-5-0-audiomanager-setmode-not-working also there's some remarks here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode(int)

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks for the links, none of them proved to be useful in solving my issue though.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding the permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE